# syntax for check debug in php codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, updates

I want to ask. why my update script doesn't work or doesn't fit with what I want. strangely this script doesn't save to the database when I click the update button but the pages move like this script is running normally (the page shouldn't move when this happens). someone who understands me with my problem please help me :(
Thanks Before

this my controller>>

```
function edit($id){
    $data['title']="Edit user";
    $this->_set_rules();
    if($this->form_validation->run()==true){
        $id=$this->input->post('id');            
        $info=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'adress'=>$this->input->post('adress'),
                'birth'=>$this->input->post('birth'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'username'=>$this->input->post('user'),
                'password'=>$this->input->post('password'),
                'level'=>$this->input->post('level'),
        ); 
        $this->m_user->update($id,$info);
        $data['user']=$this->m_user->cek($id)->row_array();
        $data['message']="<div class='alert alert-success'>the update is successful</div>";
        redirect('admin/user');
    }else{
        $data['message']="";
        $data['user']=$this->m_user->cek($id)->row_array();
        $this->template->display('admin/edit',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide us the m_user model? the update() function in particular.

Comment: through which I must tell my model m-user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your environment to "development" in index.php as follows...

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

This should make all errors be displayed.  You may also wish to turn db debugging on in config/database.php as follows...

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

Make sure that these are not switched on on a production website for obvious reasons.

You can echo out database errors as follows...

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

Comment: I don't have db.php in my config?

Comment: Sorry - database.php I think it is called.

Comment: please wait I'm trying to give it a try